# ADFS - What is best practice for limiting user access and providing user attributes

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

We have a client that we have built a webapp for and we allow their members to access this webapp via sso through an ADFS server they have provided. After implementation of the webapp the client came back to us and said that we need to query a database table in order to determine if the user that logs in via sso should be allowed to access the webapp or not. We also need to now access this table to determine what type of account this user is - i.e. are they a staff administrator, paying member or a free member

I have done several SAML/ADFS integrations but never configured ADFS myself. I am finding it hard to figure out exactly what is best practice here. I would have thought that the best practice would have been for their ADFS server to have complete control over access to the webapp and restrict based on some sort of grouping of their users. I would also expect that key attributes about the user such as TYPE come back in the response upon successful login. I am worried if we implement things the way they want we are not going to end up with a robust solution at all.

I am really looking for some advice on what is best practice and some information so I can reply with a punch because I feel their IT team who is demanding we do things in a particular way are largely attempting to avoid implementing something that they are responsible for.

Thanks for your time and advice!

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is claims based and the best practice is to restrict access based on an AD security group (in ADFS terms a role) which is passed in the token as a claim.